# Facebook Chat API - Messages are marked as spam

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xmpp, facebook-chat

I'm developing a smartphone application that allows the user to login with facebook and then send a message to his friends using the Facebook Chat API.

To achieve that I send the facebook access token to my server and then use it in a PHP script using the API to send the message on the user behalf through my application which has requested the xmpp_login permission to the user.

The process works and the message are sent and received correctly. However when the conversation is reopened those messages are not shown anymore but instead a text telling "This message is no longer available because it was identified as abusive or marked as spam" is shown.

Anybody knows why that's happening and how can I avoid that?

Comment: Are you posting the same content over and over again, including links, anything like that?

Comment: No, i'm just sending simple text messages that the user writes.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Sandbox mode to off in your app! I had the same problem and worked for me.

Comment: Answers aren't the place to ask questions. If you raise your own specific question you'll get the help you need.

Comment: this answer should be a comment